# apk upload issue

Tags: android, export, keystore, apk

I published a application in android market, now I try to upload a updated apk (version code, version name T already changed)
it gives a error that

> Upload failed You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different
>   certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate.
>   Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with
>   fingerprint(s): SHA1:
>   82:FE:C4:DA:82:B3:20:2A:84:9F:26:E4:5D:6A:AF:0A:CA:91:1D:5A and the
>   certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
>   SHA1: D2:B1:C5:7A:8A:1A:5B:FE:8C:EF:4E:3A:22:58:16:0B:89:6A:B0:AF

i need to update very soon, is anyone faced this problem or
how to resolve it.

Comment: Did you use a different keystore/key when signing?

Comment: Same key too? Keys can also change.

Comment: @A--C what shall i do..can you please give me an instructions.

Comment: You still haven't answered my second question, did you also choose the same key when exporting? The `keystore` stores the `keys` so you can have **many** keys per keystore. It sounds like you chose the wrong key. Also, are you using Eclipse to make your apk?

Comment: It is obviously a different key.  If you are using Eclipse, make sure you did not upload an .apk signed with the debug key.  Re-export a signed .apk to try again.

Comment: @A--C yeah did wrong one, now it's uploading.. thank you very much.

Comment: @iagreen yes, i did wrong, now it's uploading thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad you got your problem fixed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep your keystore *and* your **keys** consistent, otherwise the Play Store will not accept your updated app for the same store listing.

Comment: yeah i take backup now..

Answer (score 0):

You can check your debug keystore in eclipse Windows-> preferences->Android->build. Here you can check the keystore path. If both the app have different key store the change the new app key store to old one.It will solve the issue.